# Video editor able to merge files

Tags: gratis, video-editing

I'm looking for a basic video editor program with these additional characteristics:

- Able to concatenate multiple video files of the same type (at least MPG, FLV, MKV, AVI, WMV)
- Free
- If possible, able to add subtitles to the final video
- For Windows or Linux

Comment: MKV and AVI are **containers,** not video formats (I am not sure about the others). You should probably describe which codecs you want to be supported (I guess probably Mpeg-4 and AVC). Although not an editor, if you want lossless concatenation have a look at [MkvMerge](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) and its GUI. The input files may have a different container, like MP4, but the output will be within a MKV container.

Comment: `avconv` can do that, but it isn't a video editor, it's a commandline video converter...

Answer (score 4):

The easy answer is [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/):

- Concatenate Video files of the same type, ***Yes*** and can convert types to produce a single file from multiple types, plus you can extract sections of the input files to convert/concatenate
- Free ***Yes*** both gratis & open source
- Subtitle result - ***Yes*** *see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles*
- Windows & Linux - ***Yes*** & OS-X note that some Linux distros now come with avconv - generally any command that works for ffmpeg works for avconv and vice-versa.
- There is lots of documentation, books & on-line/community help available.
- There are also several GUI interfaces available.

For a simpler user interface you might also like to take a look at [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) which uses ffmpeg behind the scenes.

Comment: This is a good option. I was going to suggest the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [MPEGStreamClip](http://www.squared5.com/). It supports a lot of formats (MPEG, VOB, PS, M2P, MOD, VRO, DAT, MOV, DV, AVI, MP4, TS, M2T, MMV, REC, VID, AVR, M2V, M1V, MPV, AIFF, M1A, MP2, MPA, AC3, etc). Also you can esily edit your video files and convert them into muxed or demuxed files, or export them to QuickTime, AVI, DV and MPEG-4 files with HD quality.
The only thing that i am not sure is subtitles. But you can download it and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

[**MeGUI**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/)

Fits all your requirements.

> MeGUI is the most comprehensive GUI based ISO MPEG-4 solution. It suports MPEG-4 ASP (xvid), MPEG-4 AVC (x264), AAC, MP2, MP3, Flac, Vorbis, AC3 audio and various common containers support (MP4, MKV, AVI, M2TS).

Been using this for 5 years now.